# Add support for Edge instead of IE11 in add-ins on Office on Windows which use shared runtime

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

We develop an Excel JS Add-In which uses Shared Runtime functionality. According to the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/runtimes) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) our add-in shall be rendered using Internet Explorer 11 in Excel on Windows, regardless of the Windows and Excel versions.

As you know IE11 does not support JavaScript versions later than ES5, so tuning our add-in to support IE11 and related further maintenance is quite burdensome. Are there plans to support Edge in this scenario?

Comment: Roadmap questions don't really fit with StackOverflow. Post feature requests at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about future plans of Microsoft, not a programming question.